# LoaderManager's loaders surviving orientation change, but not activity destruction

Tags: android, loader

I need to make network calls to a backend JSON API in order to make changes server side when a user updates their profile.

Unfortunately, these asynchronous tasks might get disrupted by Android's inherent lifecycle events. So I opted to use `AsyncTaskLoader` with `getSupportLoaderManager`

However, I have again run into another problem. Although the loaders contained inside `LoaderManager` survives orientation changes - they do not survive the destruction of an activity (which is strange because `Bundle savedInstanceState` does)

```
// everything is good so far
LoaderManager.initLoader -> orientation change -> LoaderManager.getLoader(...)      = <Some Loader>
outState.putString(...)  -> orientation change -> savedInstanceState.getString(...) = <Some String>

// I am having problems now...
LoaderManager.initLoader -> activity destroyed by OS -> LoaderManager.getLoader(...)      = null
outState.putString(...)  -> activity destroyed by OS -> savedInstanceState.getString(...) = <Some String>
```

**How do I make it so that my `LoaderManager` (and more importantly the contained loaders) survives along side `savedInstanceState`**

The following is a small Android app that illustrates the current issue. Please note that the issue is only prevalent when the developer option (DONT KEEP ACTIVITIES is enabled)

https://anonfile.com/kfTft8d1b0/Android_async_loader_04.rar

1. First click the INIT loader button in the app
2. Second click the overview button
3. Third re-enter the app
4. Fourth click the GET loader button in the app
5. Observe the return value is NULL

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the android framework persisting a bundle during activity destruction, but not keeping other member variables.

onSaveInstanceState persists what you put in it and stores it on the device and then retrieves that bundle to give it to you in onCreate() if it exists.

Loader classes do not behave in this manner.

You will need to re-create the loader if the activity is destroyed.

This is the source code for loadermanager - it looks like we can enable debug logging to provide some additional insight:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android/support-v4/r7/android/support/v4/app/LoaderManager.java#LoaderManager.enableDebugLogging%28boolean%29

Comment: What are your suggestions for making the behavior of `LoaderManager` persist across activity destruction? The entire app is already completed and its in QA phase right now. We overlooked this because in early prototypes we just assumed the destruction/creation of activities was the same "destruction" that activities went through during orientation change - and therefore the same behavior was to be expected.

Comment: I don't know why. I think that is just how loaders work. They seem to survive rotation, but not the other lifecycle. And there is a distinction to be made between a LoaderManager and loader itself. but this explains the loader lifecycle and might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588511/loader-framework-and-activity-lifecycle

Comment: What id's are you using for loader id's - are they constants? If it is a big deal, then you could put in a cache layer.

Comment: Please refer to the sample application. Its really small, and I believe running it with Android studio will clarify what my problem is.

Comment: I will not be able to this evening, but if you look at the stackoverflow question mentioned above it provides insight. If I read it correctly, if the loading has not finished by the time onStop is called then the loader is canceled.

Comment: Can you override onFinish() in your activity and see if onFinish is called during screen rotation and when you do don't keep activities: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#ondestroy

Comment: The lifecycle is different.

Comment: All I wanted to do was make a simple HTTP request. :(

Comment: There is no method `onFinish`

Comment: lol - then using something like okhttp / retrofit - maybe check isFinishing() in onDestroy and see if they are different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162465/discussion-between-dazza5000-and-alanstack).